# How to link icon in laravel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I know how to link style CSS according to following code:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/styles.css') }}
```

But how to link the icon into Laravel as it is not a typical CSS file or JS file?

Comment: Just use plain ol' HTML with `asset()`: `<link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('path/to/icon') }}" type="image/x-icon">`

Answer (score 0):

You can link an image with the `HTML` helper like this:

```
{{ HTML::image("imagepath", "icon") }}
```

**OR**

```
{{asset('img/logo.png')}}
```

Comment: what I did was {{ HTML::image("fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.svg", "icon") }} and this is the path mainfolder/public/fonts/material-design-icons/Material-Design-Icons.svg